# What does the little circle next to each officer portrait mean in Sunless Skies?

Tags: sunless-skies

What does the little circle next to each officer portrait mean in Sunless Skies?

After recruiting an officer and opening the Officers interface, each officer appears as a portrait. Clicking on their portrait lets you interact with them.

At the bottom right of each portrait there is a small circle. Clicking in the circle causes the officer hat icon to appear and disappear. What does this hat mean? Multiple officers at different stations can have it enabled at the same time.

[image: Screenshot of Sunless Skies with the Officers pane open]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hat means they are assigned to that position. Officers only give their bonuses when assigned, so make sure you have them working. If they aren't, they're just fancy passengers.

You can only change which officers are assigned to each position while in port.

Comment: So if I recruit my first officer but don't click the hat, I get nothing?

Comment: @JamesCW You still get the opportunity to interact with them, which may lead to rewards and/or other encounters but you don't get the stats.

Comment: Sure, but when I recruit The Incautious Driver first thing, the text tells me I will get bonuses. It doesn't tell me that I need to click a button to make them stop freeloading in order to get the bonuses. I would think that the initial officer recruited for each slot would be automatically enabled.

Comment: @JamesCW It was that way in Sunless Sea if I recall correctly- not sure why they changed it.

Comment: I just noticed that after I hat someone, their portrait shows up small next to mine in the bottom right. I wonder if I just didn't read the tutorial auto-popups or something.

Comment: Also! You can only make changes to officer assignments while in port?! Studoku, maybe edit that into your answer, I feel like that is important information.